# Parsing tuple entry to string

Tags: python, parsing

I have a tuple say, `tuple_A = (1,2,3,4)`. I would like to parse this tuple so that it would show as 1.2.3.4 as a string.

Is there any way to do in Python built-in function?

Comment: `print(".".join(str(i) for i in tuple_A))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
".".join(str(i) for i in tuple_A)
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I wanted to accept the answer, but it didn't allow me to do so. Sorry for asking stupid question, I am new here.

Comment: Rahman81 you'll have to give it a couple more minutes before you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
'.'.join(map(str, tuple_A))
```

---

The explanation:

`map(str, tuple_A)` will apply the `str` function to every element of the `tuple_A` - giving something as

```
(str(1), str(2), str(3), str(4))
```

i. e.

```
('1', '2', '3', '4')
```

Then the method `'.'.join()` concatenates individual elements with the '.' delimiter, giving the resulting string.

The result:

> ```
> '1.2.3.4'
> ```